# When taxiing a taildragger across a kerb, is it best to cross straight-on or at an angle?

Tags: taxiing, tail-dragger

The grass taxiways at my local aerodrome are sometimes crossed by hard surfaces. Where they cross, the levels don't quite match, so there's a bump as you cross: not quite a pavement kerb, but still a sudden change in surface height.

What's the best way to cross these safely? Crossing straight-on carries the risk that the mainwheels will both stick against the ledge, lifting your tail and in extreme cases maybe causing a prop strike; like trying to cycle up a kerb and going over the handlebars. Crossing at an angle makes sticking less likely, but it rolls the aircraft slightly, and in a low-wing airplane you risk touching a wing-tip.

What's the best way to balance these risks and safely cross the kerb?

Comment: Is it possible to put some kind of support to make level difference less? Maybe a sand bag or some pipe so the cross is lower or less vertical?

Comment: Opinion: Taxi diagonally to minimize nose-over risk, if the wing tips are too close to ground, don't taxi there. Pull the plane straight over the step manually in this case, tail first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The rule I was always taught is to cross any 'step' - up or down - at an angle with the elevator full back:

- It minimizes the chance of a prop strike, which is much more expensive than a wingtip strike
- When going 'up', you avoid having both wheels up against the step at the same time, which usually means you need a burst of power to get over it, which could lead to sudden acceleration and sharp braking
- When going 'down' you avoid the aircraft dropping down suddenly, with the same risks of strikes or an increase in speed
- Lifting the elevator reduces the chance of it striking

There may be some differences for specific aircraft types, but I've always followed that advice and never had a problem. I've also never seen an aircraft get close to a wingtip strike doing this, but I suppose it could happen if the step is large enough. Although in that case you might want to just find another taxi route.

Comment: This is true of both tricycle and taildraggers.